# Angular js with Parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning how angular js works with parse backend. This is my code:

```
angular.module('AuthApp', []).controller(['ctrl', function($scope) {
    Parse.initialize("PfF63Z7XdWtctidrATGigEFQsHh6aui6V68BmWSU", "GIpF3DJGBfprXAml5GLMPhCuldAnyXDLNY41M7zV");
    $scope.submit()=function(){    
        var Person = Parse.Object.extend("person"); 
        var person = new Person();
        person.set("name", $scope.name);
        person.set("email", $scope.email);
        person.save();
    }
}]);
```

Comment: and what is the output/error

Comment: there is no error but i dnt have any new class with name Person

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to save form data in parse.This is the link:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rnHtF

Comment: Firstly $scope.submit should not have ( ) after it, secondly you need to better explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to initialise Parse in the app.js  that way it's only called once. I'm unsure whether having it run in the controller would be a problem (that may depend on how your controller is used), but in any case you don't want it initialised every time a controller is instantiated.

I have my Parse initialisation in the run method following the execution of config in the module config

This way the Parse API is available to any controller wherever its needed.

eg:

```
    angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config( ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
     //route provider stuff
  }])
  .run(function() {  
          Parse.initialize('mg4MQuTvHvSxppLwkSdxaidaosudaoudaoudaoudao', '59a89989asdklasdlkahdahdahasdhasdahdashkLLL');  
 });
```